# Is Xamarin provided preview page?

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, layout

I'm new in Xamarin. I want to know if Xamarin provide preview layout page, because i already search and did not find it.Hope u guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

Android Studio Preview.
[image: Android Studio Preview]

Comment: Xamarin Forms has a XAML Preview window, Xamarin Android doesn't

Comment: You can see 3D preview using AXML.

Answer (score 0):

has a layout preview facilitator, you do not have to compile the entire project to see if you just change the layout (xaml)

Below is the link related to this plugin.

https://grialkit.com/gorilla-player/